# JLabel does not wrap when using <pre>

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, pre

I can successfully wrap normal HTML text in a `JLabel`. But when I use `pre` it doesn't seem to wrap.

Here's what I have set the text in my `JLabel` to:

```html
<html><pre face=\"Arial\" style = \"white-space:pre-wrap;\">" + temp +  "</pre></html>
```

this same html code works when I test it on w3school's tryit editor (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_wrap)

Please provide the simplest solution possible.

Comment: *"Please provide the simplest solution possible."* Please ask a question.

Comment: BTW - Swing's support for CSS is very patchy & rudimentary. It simply does not support `white-space:pre-wrap;`.

Comment: "this same html code works when I test it on w3school's" - this is a WRONG statement. You have just overlooked that it displays <pre>.

Comment: @mentallurg I don't understand what you are saying, can you please clarify?

Comment: @AndrewThompson my quesion is how do I wrap my JLabel using <pre> in html. Isn't it obvious?

"It simply does not support white-space:pre-wrap;" - ok, thanks. can you please provide another solution for me? I absolutely have to use html as I'm using a combination of text and images (ie: when one types certain syntax such as "WS" then "WS.png" will be displayed in place).

Comment: *"Isn't it obvious?"* It is when you [edit] the question to **include that information.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson I still feel the question shows that I'm looking to try and wrap using <pre> in Java. that being said, let's move on from this, apologies if I came across offensive. People on this site appear rude to me so it's quite a culture shock. 

anyway, is there another solution I could use? to clarify:

- must be html, reason is using images and text combined by means of keywords (as my WS example above).
- needs to work like "pre" in that I can use spacebar instead of &nbsp
- needs to wrap

thank you

Comment: Preformatted text was never intended to word wrap. I can't speak to the W3 Schools (AKA W3 fools) test. An HTML construct that can perhaps give the effect you seem to be wanting is an HTML `<textarea>`, having said that, I'm a bit confused about the effect you're trying to achieve with 'wrapped but preformatted' text. Other components that can display HTML (perhaps .. slightly better) are a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your reply. 

a textarea can't use html from what I know. I googled and tried myself and didn't seem to find a way to do that?

the effect I am looking for is this:

my project is a card creator for a card game I'm inventing (hence my poor programming skills, haven't touched java since high school). the point of using html is to be able to type in a textarea, "Deal 1 dmg" and instead of "dmg" it will show an icon (on the Jlabel or whatever else). I've already done the "dmg" thing successfully.

Comment: @AndrewThompson pre text can wrap in html from what I can see? https://longren.io/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/

the point of <pre> is that it was difficult to format the cards using &nsbp and <br> etc. So I found with <pre> one can just type and use spaces via the spacebar and enter for a new line. And I did see you can wrap <pre> in html but as you said above, Swing's support for CSS is very patchy.

Comment: jEditorPane and jTextPane work with the html but I'm not sure how to wrap them. I'm looking online but, please forgive my ignorance, I'm doing this app once-off just because my team needs it, and this is my final task to finish. Is there a simple solution you can provide to wrap a JEditorPane/JTextpane please?

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of `<pre>` is to keep the text formatting as is. **pre** is for "**pre**serve formatting". It will never wrap.

On the page you named it could not work. Probably you have placed your code inside the `<textarea>`? The `<textarea>` interprets `<pre>` not as a tag, but as a normal text and you saw also the `<pre>` in the result window. Didn't you? May be you have just overlooked it.

Comment: "On the page you named it could not work.Probably you have placed your code inside the <textarea>?" - no I deleted the textarea and put <html><pre face="Arial" style = "white-space:pre-wrap;">"text"</pre></html>

it DID wrap there. you CAN wrap <pre>